# Laravel Eloquent Inner Join

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

This is the query I currently using for `Inner Join` in my laravel app:

```
public function getReservationListAPI()
    {
        $id = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()->id;

        $result = DB::table('pporders AS ord')
            ->join('products AS pd', 'ord.product_id', '=', 'pd.id')
            ->select('ord.*')
            ->where('pd.user_id',$id)
            ->get();
        dd($result);

    }
```

How can I wrote this query in Eloquent form? Thanks!!

---

### EDIT

Relationship:

```
Product hasMany Order
Order belongsTo Product
User hasMany Product
Product belongsTo User
```

Comment: What type of relationship is it? One to One, One to Many or Many to Many ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your relation, but something like this:

```
Pporders::with(['product' => function($q) use($id) {
    $q->where('user_id', $id);
}])->get();
```

But it won't make the same sql query what you described, but gives the same result.

Comment: Changed according to your relationships. So your order has only one product.